# Limit # in array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script that displays users who have published on my site.... Im wondering how I can set the limit that is shown to 10.. I'm new to PHP.. Would I be able to use a foreach to achieve this?

```
   <?php
// Display the widget title   
if ( $title )  {
    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;  
}

$args = array(
    'role' => $role,
    'orderyby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$user_ids = get_users($args);

    foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
        if ($postcount) {
            if(count_user_posts($user_id->ID)>0) {
                echo '<a class="cuda-gravatar" href="'.get_author_posts_url($user_id->ID).'" title="'.$user_id->display_name.'">';
                    echo get_avatar($user_id->ID, $size);
                echo '</a>';
            } else {

            }
        } else {
            echo '<a class="cuda-gravatar" href="'.get_author_posts_url($user_id->ID).'" title="'.$user_id->display_name.'">';
                echo get_avatar($user_id->ID, $size);
            echo '</a>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: add LIMIT 10 to your sql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (`number`):

```
$args = array(
    'role' => $role,
    'orderyby' => 'post_count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'number' => 10 // <-- add this
);
```

You may also use `offset`, read more on [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) about `get users()`.

Comment: Thanks... the 'number' solution worked temporarily but as new users registered it started actually showing less users. I have no idea whats going on here, but the more new users the less it shows. If i increase the number to like 25, it will then show a few more...

Comment: oh man this is stupid.. it was the typo in "orderyby"... hahaha, your answer is correct minus that.. that typo produced the weirdest behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way would be to set a limit to your sql query

```
$args = array(
    ...
    'posts_per_page' => 10 
);
```

or your can add a counter

```
foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
  $i++
  ...
  if($i==10){break;}

}
```